# Ambiguous use of subscript xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have this code:

```
var jsonResult = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
var count = jsonResult["levels"]!.count as Int
for var i=0; i<count; ++i {
   let obj = jsonResult["levels"]![i] as! NSDictionary
   ...
}
```

On the last line I am receiving this error:

> Ambiguous use of subscript

How can I resolve this?

This code has worked for some time but with the upgrade to xcode 7.1 it broke and stopped working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler what the intermediary object is in the line

```
let obj = jsonResult["levels"]![i] as! NSDictionary
```

After the statement `jsonResult["levels"]!` the compiler does not know what kind of object he is dealing with. You have to tell it that is an `NSArray` or something else:

```
let obj = (jsonResult["levels"] as! NSArray)[i] as! NSDictionary
```

Of course you should additionally make sure that you can actually do all that casting and that the objects inside the json are really of the expected type.

---

Even a little bit shorter using only one cast by directly casting to an array of `NSDictionary`:

```
let obj = (jsonResult["levels"] as! [NSDictionary])[i]
```

The reasoning remains the same: you tell the compiler of what type `jsonResult["levels"]`. It is supposed to be an array containing `NSDictionary`s.

Answer (score 0):

In the new Swift update. You should get your value with `objectForKey("yourKey")` method rather than `["yourKey"]`. In your case,

```
let obj = jsonResult.objectForKey("levels")![i] as! NSDictionary
```