# ambiguous use of subscript Swift 2.3

Tags: swift, parse-platform

i've a problem with my project, I get the following error

> Ambiguous use of subscript

on this line

```
 else if (listOfEveryting[indexPath.row - 1].objectForKey("text")![0] as! Int) == 1{
```

Can you help me ?
thanks a lot !

Comment: What is `listOfEveryting`'s type?

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33592699/ambiguous-use-of-subscript-xcode-7-1

Comment: var listOfEveryting:[PFObject]! = []

Comment: Post the PFObject/JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objectForKey("text")` returns `AnyObject`. It could be a dictionary (key subscription) or an array (index subscription), that's the ambiguity.

Since you know the expected type use optional bindings with downcasting to help the compiler

```
else if let array = listOfEveryting[indexPath.row - 1]["text"] as? [Int], 
      firstObject = array.first where firstObject == 1 {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
else if let dictionary: NSDictionary = listOfEveryting[indexPath.row - 1], let intArray = dictionary.objectForKey("text") as? NSArray, let theInt = intArray[0] as? Int where theInt == 1 {
```

If it doesn't work, at least it should give you more insight.